# Prevent Unknown robot from crawling my website and save bandwidth

Tags: php, web, drupal-7

I have a drupal operated small website. It is not commercial, ie: no income from it. The site is in shared host, so has limited bandwidth and resource.
This site encounters "Bandwidth exceed" problem every month because more than 60% of bandwidth is being used by bots and spiders. The maximum is gone to:

Unknown robot (identified by 'bot' followed by a space or one of the following characters _+:,.;/-)

Out of 10GB Bandwidth, 1 GB goes to googlebot (It's OK)

6 GB goes to Unknown robot (identified by 'bot' followed by a space or one of the following characters _+:,.;/-).

500MB goes to unknown bots identified as robot

Other 500 MB goes to bots identified as spider, crawl, empty user-agent etc.

So what remains? less than 2GB for the visitors.

How could I identify or block the bad bots? Please suggest me some way to prevent it.

Comment: robots.txt solution: http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/blockjustbad.html